# Fast update a big list (>50M) using RCPP

Tags: c++, r, performance, subset, rcpp

I am quite new to `RCPP`and `C++`.

I was trying to **fast** update a huge list (59M elements) using a piece of code I wrote in C++ and I am almost there. It works and it is 12k faster.

**EDIT:**

**Is there any faster way of updating single elements of a list?** *(my original question was solved in comments.)*

Below there are a simplified example with a small list and a benchmark with a large list.

INPUT example:

```
set.seed(311)
L <- lapply(1:5, function (x) {rnorm(sample(1:5, size = 1, replace = T))} )

L[[1]] 
[1] 9 7 8 3
```

OUTPUT R code:

```
new_element <- c(1, 2)
k = 1L
L[[k]] <- c(L[[k]], new_element)

L[[k]]
[1] 9 7 8 3 1 2
```

FUNCTION RCPP Code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
List assign_list(List x, int k, NumericVector upd){
  // initialize an accumulator variable

  NumericVector xk = x[k-1];
  NumericVector y = NumericVector(xk.size() + upd.size());

  for(int i = 0; i < xk.size(); ++i) {
    y[i] = xk[i];
  }

  int i = 0;
  for(int j = xk.size(); j < y.length(); ++j) {
    y[j] = upd[i];
    i += 1;
  }

  x[k-1] = y;

  return(y);

}
```

OUTPUT RCPP code

```
set.seed(311)
L <- lapply(1:5, function (x) {sample(1:10, sample(1:5, size = 1, replace = T))} )

assign_list(L, 1L, new_element)
L[[k]] 
[1] 9 7 8 3 1 2
```

BENCKMARK

```
set.seed(311)
L_big <- lapply(1:10000000, function (x) {sample(1:10, sample(1:5, size = 1, replace = T))} )
microbenchmark(times = 5L,
  "r"   = L_big[[k]] <- c(L_big[[k]], new_element),
  "C++" = assign_list(L_big, k, new_element)
)

Unit: microseconds
 expr   min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval cld
    r 9.625 199263.953 163516.4662 201014.890 205111.533 212182.330     5   b
  C++ 3.850     14.758     13.4744     15.078     15.399     18.287     5  a 
>
```

Comment: @李哲源 if I change it to `List assign_list` it works. Do you think the code is done in a proper way or shall I change something?

Comment: What is `C_ids`?

Comment: @F.Privé, The right code is L[[k]] and not C_ids[[K]]. I corrected the mistake